# Combining two javascript statement

Tags: javascript

I am trying to combine two statements that I have gotten to work individually. What I want is for a specific web page to redirect to different URLs if certain conditions are met.

First, I want the page to redirect, if the visitor is not coming from a specific page (parental consent form); they will be redirected to an "access denied page". This is the code I am using for that:

```js
<<script> 
<!-- Hide script from old browsers
    if (document.referrer != "https://www.civicchangemakers.com/codecivic/parental-consent")
    window.location.replace("https://www.civicchangemakers.com/access-denied"); 
//-- Stop hiding script --> 
</script>
```

Next, if the visitor has completed the parental-consent form at an earlier time and is trying to access this same page again, I would like for the page to redirect to a different page. The code I got to work for that is:

```js
<script>
 {
  window.history.go("https://www.civicchangemakers.com/codecivic/parental-consent");
  window.location.replace("https://www.civicchangemakers.com/next-steps");
}
</script>
```

How would I combine the two statements so that it runs the first condition and then the second condition?

Thanks.

Comment: You should not rely on the referrer value; it is trivial to spoof.

Comment: Don't use the referrer value for that, set a cookie instead. That will also trivially enable your second use case.

Comment: Also calling `window.history.go()` and then immediately `window.history.replace()` doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. How would I set a cookie? I am a novice at coding by the way.